# SAPI rate formula evaluation

Tags: c++, text-to-speech

I have created a computer voice, and I would like to treat the rate command correctly.

The Microsoft whitepaper says this about the rate (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717037(v=vs.85).aspx):

Rate:

The Rate tag controls the rate of a voice. The tag can be empty, in which case it applies to all subsequent text, or it can have content, in which case it only applies to that content. The Rate tag has two attributes, Speed and AbsSpeed, one of which must be present. The value of these attributes should be an integer between negative ten and ten. Values outside of this range may be truncated by the engine (but are not truncated by SAPI). The AbsSpeed attribute controls the absolute rate of the voice, so a value of ten always corresponds to a value of ten; a value of five always corresponds to a value of five.

This text should be spoken at rate five.

This text should be spoken at rate negative five.

All text which follows should be spoken at rate ten.

I haven't found any indication of what rate should actually be converted to. However, I would like to stay confirm with Microsoft's computer voice.

I did some tests using a sample sentence.

Microsoft's own computer voice produced the following outputs with a sample sentence ("This is a test."):

Rate 8:
1,15 sec

Rate 0:
2,65 sec

Rate -8:
6,35 sec

However, I don't see a real formula behind this. 
My attempt of

```
float f1 = (rate / 10.0f);
float fSpeed = 1+f1;
```

doesn't seem to correspond to MS's output length at all.

I feed this value to sonicChangeFloatSpeed in the famous libSonic library.

At rate -8, my voice's output is ~12 seconds while Microsoft's voice's output is ~6 sec.

Can anybody estimate a formula behind MS's voice rate?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Microsoft has quite a few SAPI5 voices - which one are you using as your reference?  You might find it more useful to use a non MS voice as reference since some are much better - and they may have paid more attention to details such as  consistent rate variation . IMO  IVONA do v.good English voices.

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff I can assure you as a developer that Microsoft did a great job on their voices. Any tags supported, all events fired, all data conversion done brilliantly. Ivona is not so good at it in the languages I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using IVONA 2 Amy (English UK) SAPI5 Voice reading the phrase `One Two Three Four Five.` I get a strictly linear relation for duration v. the slowing (negative) rate.
But for the speeding (positive) rate the relation is not the same.  It could be linear with a different slope.

```
Rate Duration (s)   
-10 3.0   150%
-9  2.9   145%
-8  2.8   140%
-7  2.7   135%
-6  2.6   130%
-5  2.5   125%
-4  2.4   120%
-3  2.3   115%
-2  2.2   110%
-1  2.1   105%
 0  2.0   100%
+1  1.8   90%
+2  1.7   85%
+3  1.6   80%
+4  1.4   70%
+5  1.3   65%
+6  1.1   55%
+7  1.0   50%
+8  0.8   40%
+9  0.7   35%
+10 0.5   25%
```

Since there are only 21 discrete levels you could avoid a formula and simply use the percentage **lookup table** that I provide above in column 3. Here is the plot for your inspection.

[image: Plot of duration v. rate]

Comment: Are you sure? Could this be put into a formula?

Comment: @tmighty rather than a formula I give you a lookup table that you can use find the multiplier  you need for each of the 21 different rates